# Mark a .CSV file if it has been read

Tags: php, csv, permissions

I have two WordPress sites on two different servers. Site B creates a .CSV file with the latest comments. Site A reads that file and gets the information and performs some functions on it. These are two independent processes that are on separate servers.

I create the CSV in 'append' mode so that I can compile the new comments without fear of skipping any while running the function on the other side:

```
$fp = fopen('new_comments.csv', 'a');
```

However, once I get the .CSV on Site A, I have no way to write to the .CSV and tell it that I have read the contents.

I suppose I could overwrite the .CSV data in 'w' mode and only run it once right before I run the other function, but is there any other way to make sure that once I read from the .CSV on Site A, I can refresh the .CSV on Site B?

Answer (score 0):

Use the filesystem function [filemtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to get the last modification time of the file. You can then do a check in your second server to see if it has been already read.

Similarly, you can do it with the size of the file.

(You could also put a time period of "Grace" between the two servers to do a check in there).

Comment: How would I distinguish between a last-modified 'insert' time and a last-modified 'read' time?

Comment: There is also [fileatime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filatime.php) if you are going into that way. I am more inclined to check the filesize between a time window though.